# Are there real-world devices similar to the thrust reversers in this scene in Star Wars?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, rocket-science, propulsion

In [Star Wars 3 in the initial crash scene](https://youtu.be/yZBSyLrOpX4?t=190) where a spaceship enters the atmosphere for an emergency landing the thrust engine is blocked by a part of the ship and absorbs a part of the thrust which suggests that it's used as a brake.

I'd be interested if that could work inside or outside an atmosphere. However I have few ideas and practical experience approaching such a topic.

I'm aware that Star Wars is fictional, but the pictured engine and brake are a feasible design. Maybe it doesn't make sense, but it was so long ago that they didn't know any better. I spent some time to figure out whether the question belongs here, in case it doesn't I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devices pictured in that scene are clearly modelled on [thrust reversers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_reversal#Jet_aircraft), which are real devices used in a wide variety of jet engines.

Here is one of them in action on a regional jet airliner:

[image]

<sup>[Image source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Klm_f100_ph-kle_arp.jpg)</sup>

For more details, see the first link above.